# How and where can I test a crypt algorithm?

Tags: security, encryption

I have developed a simple algorithm to crypt short string and text.

I am now doing some local test and stress test on it to ensure both speed and leek, but how and where can I test it for its security?

Comment: Why did you develop your own algorithm for this? Plenty of well-tested algorithms exist in the public domain, and as you're finding out, introducing a new one is hard. What is the capability your algorithm offers that the established ones do not?

Comment: It introduces just that it is simple, light, reversible, and it can be parameterized and adjusted to its specific usage by the developer. He can even let the application user tweak and adjust it for extra security and user peace of mind.

Comment: Jlouro, AES has all of those capabilities. And letting a user tweak crypto settings is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't take offense but this is generally a horribly bad idea.  While it may be interesting to roll your own it is unlikely anything you can come up with will be as well vetted as AES, RSA, or SHA.  Even if it was "better" (faster, stronger, more flexible) the danger is in not knowing of cryptographic flaws.  True vetting takes years (decades) and the independent analysis by thousands of experts in the field.  Often to break an algorithm it requires researcher A to discover an issue and writes a paper which leads to a theoretical break in another paper, finally someone turns that into a potential exploit (like defeating 11 rounds of 16 round cipher), and lastly years later a true flaw.

It took over two years to choose Rijndael as the AES and it competed against hundreds of other algorithms.

**The problem with bad security is that when it breaks often you simply don't know it is broken.** Bad security can look like good security for years until suddenly a database of you customer's confidential information ends up for sale in some former Soviet bloc country you never heard of.

---

*No one can duplicate the confidence that RSA offers after 20 years of cryptanalytic review.*

Bruce Schneier

**Some things you can do:**

- Make the implementation completely open.  Source code, design diagrams, theory, everything.  If you feel the need to hide **any part** of the implementation it isn't secure it is merely security through obscurity.  A good system will be designed under the assumption that the attacker will have the cipher, the cipher text, the salt, and possibly even a limited amount of plaintext & ciphertext pairs.
- Get it peer reviewed.  This may be very difficult without significant academic or professional credentials.
- Offer a prize to attract attention.  Get a $1000 Amazon gift card and encrypt it with your algorithm.  Post it on a public server and try to get as much publicity as possible.
- Find some outlandish claim to stake your rep on.  If it is faster than AES at same key length then make that claim.  Try to give people a reason to attack your cipher.  It will be difficult to attract real talent to an unknown cipher.  Nobody may break your cipher but that may just mean the true experts simply don't know or care.

---

We live in a very good time when it comes to encryption.  There are dozens of open, publicly available, heavily vetted algorithms for virtually every scenario. People everyday are researching ways to break AES, RSA, and SHA and that provides a level of assurance that is impossible with a "homebrew" cipher.

Just because nobody breaks your algorithm doesn't mean it is secure.  It is like trying to prove a negative.  Nobody has broken your algorithm and nobody has broken AES.  The only difference is that AES has thousands of people actively trying and they have been trying for years now.  While either **could** be vulnerable to crypographic flaw I know where I would put my money.

Answer (score 3):

Open Source it.

And if you are serious: write a paper about it and submit to a conference. Cryptography is nothing you should do alone at home. Only other humans can really "stress test" it.

Comment: The open source part and the collaboration is my goal here.

Answer (score 3):

I think Martin Schapendonk is right.

E.g. you could make a contest with some cheap prizes (Amazon vouchers).

Comment: Ok. That is cool. How can I implement that? Any simple ideas ?

Comment: You will hardly get the attention of serious security researchers with cheap prizes. But this might help you find really obvious flaws. On the other hand, if you posted your work here, we might also give you hints.

Answer (score 1):

Release it to the public :-)